# I would like to reproduce the plot of the series and modify the values ​present on the x axis

Tags: r

I would like to ask for help. I'm analyzing a univariate time series on Rstudio. I would like to reproduce the plot of the series and modify the values ​​present on the x axis. the time series is saved in a txt file. this is my code:

```
dati <- read.table("positivi.txt", header=TRUE)
plot.ts(dati, main="positivi giornaliei",col=4)
```

On the x axis I would like to insert the dates, how can I do?

The data file consists of 123 observations of integer values

```
dput(head(newdati,123))

c(245L, 127L, 252L, 243L, 300L, 271L, 223L, 135L, 82L, 244L, 
212L, 201L, 175L, 229L, 109L, 41L, 235L, 215L, 125L, 113L, 131L, 
107L, 37L, 143L, 156L, 126L, 110L, 124L, 71L, 27L, 146L, 124L, 
96L, 95L, 116L, 116L, 32L, 190L, 103L, 108L, 71L, 69L, 64L, 59L, 
120L, 122L, 160L, 138L, 122L, 148L, 45L, 154L, 163L, 201L, 172L, 
159L, 131L, 44L, 63L, 225L, 200L, 173L, 228L, 159L, 62L, 184L, 
152L, 218L, 153L, 183L, 112L, 70L, 199L, 262L, 158L, 156L, 208L, 
151L, 109L, 217L, 244L, 224L, 250L, 331L, 158L, 127L, 319L, 381L, 
244L, 347L, 374L, 253L, 155L, 361L, 571L, 146L, 417L, 621L, 284L, 
209L, 547L, 474L, 497L, 399L, 705L, 463L, 188L, 501L, 684L, 688L, 
719L, 601L, 161L, 366L, 1169L, 1060L, 1402L, 738L, 355L, 136L, 
211L, 480L, 504L)
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please post the output of `dput(head(dati, 20))` in the question, like this we can't answer the question.

Comment: the data file consists of 123 observations of integer values

Comment: When did the series start? And how many observations per unit of time do you have, is the series daily, monthly, etc data?

Comment: are given daily, for each day I have a value.
the time period runs from 4th September 2021 to 4th January 2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `ggplot2` graph, create a `dates` variable with `seq.Date` and then plot the data in a R 4.1.0 pipe.

```
library(ggplot2)

start <- as.Date("2021-09-04")
dates <- seq(start, by = "1 day", length.out = length(dati))

data.frame(dati, dates) |>
  ggplot(aes(dates, dati)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "week", date_labels = "%d %b %Y") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

---

### Edit

To have a background without the grid lines and the x axis labels perpendicular to the axis, define a custom theme. Then remove all themes, including`theme_bw`, and use `theme_Giuseppina()` instead of them.

```
theme_Giuseppina <- function(){
  theme_bw() %+replace%
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)
  )
}
```

Comment: sorry, i tried the code but it brings me this error:  ** Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.**

Comment: @Giuseppina The first 3 code lines were not formated as code, see if the error goes away if you run the entire code.

Comment: is it possible to get the completely white background in the plot?

Comment: @Giuseppina Yes, it is. Instead of `theme_bw()` use `theme_classic()`.

Comment: @Giuseppina Or create a custom theme. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You more than likely need to use the `axis()` command to do this.
It will be something along the lines of

```
plot.ts(dati, main="positivi giornaliei",col=4, xaxt = 'n')
axis(1, at = 1:length(dati), labels = yourLabels)
```

where `yourLabels` is a vector with all your dates in.

`xaxt = 'n'` stops the x-axis from being plotted, and then the `axis()` command adds a new one in

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. With axis I don't get exactly what I wanted. I only print some dates, I wanted to see more points. Also I would like the dates to be printed vertically with a different format. I don't want to display the dd-mm-yyyy format, but I would like dd month yy